# Nonworking Markdown in support email response

Tags: bug, status-completed, email

I recently requested an account merge. The Markdown in the support team's email doesn't render.

Did they forget...

- to run their email through a Markdown parser before sending?
- that Gmail (and most other major email services) does not parse Markdown?

Screenshots (desktop and mobile) of the mess-up for your convenience.

[image: desktop]
[image: mobile]

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a very bad mess-up (if at all). Isn't Markdown designed to be human-readable? Anyways, it should still be translated to HTML.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I doubt the team meant the email to look like that, which makes it a mess-up. However small a mess-up is, it's still a mess-up.

Comment: I'm marking ZenDesk down for that.

Comment: Repro here. I've received an email on Feb 20 with the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, so this was a fun one to work out. Apparently we had explicitly switched our reply trigger over to using unformatted emails a while ago because we hated all the fancy borders and other nonsense that ZenDesk insisted on incorporating into the messages when using the formatted options.

**Our adventure begins trying to do it with ZenDesk alone.**

ZenDesk just blatantly does not support iterating through the list of comments which are formatted so you can make the email look how you want (in our case, as plain as possible because we want users to see the information, not all the graphics and other stuff that distracts them). They only provide a *single* array that can be iterated and it only provides the unformatted comments that you saw in your email. Ugh. Looks like we can't do anything about this without re-introducing all the clutter.

**Here comes Liquid for Designers, to save the day!**

We'd been using very basic Liquid to create the email itself, but had never really explored all of its capabilities. Turns out, it has a few options that can come in very useful in trying to get around ZenDesk's irritating limitations on how you format emails. So in trying to figure out how we could utilize this to our advantage, we did some analyzing on how ticket replies work. This is what we came up with:

You already have all your replies to the conversation in your email client, so we don't *need* to keep sending you the entire conversation every time we reply. We could just send you our reply, in a formatted way, and be done with it.

Wellll, problem. For the majority of our users, the *first* and original message is automatically generated via an email sent from the contact us submission form. It won't be in your email, because you didn't send it from your email. We really should include that initial correspondence so the user knows exactly what they said and what we're replying to.

**A happy fairy tale ending.**

So, our ingenious solution is to include it (ha). Using Liquid, we set up a small system where if there are only two comments on the ticket (your original message and our reply to it), then we'll attach the original message in a blockquote below our formatted reply to it. Since the original message was sent from a submission form that never formatted your text as Markdown to begin with, it doesn't need to be run through Markdown - it can just be inserted as plain text. All further replies (where there are more than two comments on the ticket) will *only* send our reply with nothing else below it.

So, moving forward, all of our *replies* will be formatted correctly with the Markdown. The very *first* reply you receive from us in a chain will also contain the original message you submitted. This change to our emails will go live shortly.

Comment: Reading answers to meta bug/fr questions is, sadly, more educative than reading main SO proper.